# Why I cannot and how I can assign a return value of function to object property?

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties

Thank you for ideas!

Console: "Uncaught TypeError: program.test is not a function..."

```js
let program = {
  name: "...something..."
};

program.wantedKeys = program.test();

program.test = () => "test";

console.log(program.wantedKeys);
```

...ideally I would like to see it with "this." too...

Thanks!

Comment: you try to call program.test before it is defined. Switch line 5 and 7

Comment: Thank you! I'm blushing for such "basic" O:-) ... I just somehow wanted to keep "constant" properties above functions for better readability in further program...

Answer (score -1):

You definitely can assign function return value to object property, please check example below:

```js
let obj = {
  test: () => {
      return 'return-value';
  }
}

obj.another_propery = obj.test();

console.log(obj);
```

It's just that in your example, `test` property is defined on `program` object after it was called.

Cheers. :)

Comment: "It's just that in your example, test property is not defined on program object" — Yes, it is. Just not until after the attempt to call it.

Comment: @Quentin: You are 100% right. I missed that the property was defined after the call. Will edit the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Exactly as the error says, "program.test is not a function...". You need to define the test property within the program object before you can call it. For example:

```js
let program = {
  name: "...something...",
  test: () => "test"
};

program.wantedKeys = program.test();

console.log(program.wantedKeys);
```